# BaseClass types within an Abstract Class

Tags: c++

I have the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct BaseResult {
  virtual ~BaseResult() = default;
};

class BaseClass {
  public:

  virtual ~BaseClass() = default;

  virtual void impl(int test) = 0;

  virtual void run(BaseResult result) = 0;
};

struct DerivedResult : BaseResult {
  DerivedResult() {}
};

class DerivedClassA : public BaseClass {
  private:
  int custom = 0;

  public:

  DerivedClassA() {}

  static void run() {}

  void impl(int test) {
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
  }

  void run(DerivedResult result) {};

  ~DerivedClassA() = default;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> items;
  items.emplace_back(std::make_shared<DerivedClassA>());

  for (const auto& item : items)
    item->impl(5);

  return 0;
}
```

In this case, I have defined a `BaseClass` to have a method called `run` that accepts a `BaseResult`. And in the derived version of `BaseClass` / `DerivedClassA` i have that method implemented but it takes a derived class of `BaseResult`.

However, doing this results in a compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at(DerivedClassA*&)'
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'DerivedClassA'
```

Comment: Have you tried to `override` the methods ? That usually clears out doubt.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Certainly does in this case :)

Comment: I tried `void post(DerivedResult result) override {};` but i got `error: 'void DerivedClassA::post(DerivedClassA::DerivedResult)' marked 'override', but does not override`

Comment: _" but does not override"_ - tadaa - so, it does not override. What does that tell you?

Comment: So does this approach of having a derived class take an input a derived member not work at all?

Comment: Setting aside for a moment the fact that it's not valid C++. How do you expect it to work? If I write `BaseClass* p = new DerivedClassA(); BaseResult r; p->run(r);` what exactly is supposed to happen? What function should get called, with what parameter?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24438735/51831

Answer (score 0):

This can't work, even thoretically. If you think about what the declaration of `run` in the base class says, it means "every instance of this class, or of the derived class will have a method run taking a `BaseResult`. If you try to override it in the derived class with a method taking a `DerivedResult`, that would break this contract (because it would "refuse" or somehow not work with a `BaseResult` that's not a `DerivedResult`). In theory, the only thing you could hope for would be *contra*-variance in the argument type, eg. the derived class would take an argument of a *more general* type than the base. However, this can't be done in C++. The argument list **must** be the same as in the base class.

It's for a good reason, too: In other languages, which do allow contravariant argument types in overriden methods, the contravariance relies on the fact that you can't overwrite the passed object (eg. `*arg = obj`). In C++, you can do that which would result in headaches due to only part of the object being overwritten, and its state thus being inconsistent.

The only difference in the derived class of a virtual method signature can be *co*-variance of the return type, *if it is a pointer or a reference*. Eg.

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual BaseResult* f() = 0;
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    DerivedResult* f() override;
};
```

Comment: In other words, this violates Liskov Substitution Principle.